# Having problems building an Active Record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, ruby, activerecord

I have a small application which records all the minutes we spend on some projects at work.
I'm having troubles retrieving data from db.

My models:

```
WorkingDay
  has_many :tasks
  belongs_to :user
  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
```

```
Task
  belongs_to :working_day
  belongs_to :project
```

```
Project
    belongs_to :user, required: false
    belongs_to :company, required: false
    
    has_many :tasks
```

```
Company
  has_many :projects
```

```
User
  belongs_to :role, required: false

  has_many :projects
  has_many :working_days
```

I'm exporting data into XLSX, following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@JasonCodes/ruby-on-rails-exporting-data-to-excel-b3b204281085) and I would like to do two thing:

1. In the first sheet, I'd like to order the projects by name;
2. In the other sheets, I'd like to group projects by company.

This is my code snippet:

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook

wb.add_worksheet(name: "All") do |sheet|
  wd = WorkingDay.where(day_date: Date.strptime("2022-09-01", '%Y-%m-%d')..Date.strptime("2022-09-27", '%Y-%m-%d')).includes(:user).includes(tasks: :project)

  ta = {}
  
  wd.each do |wd|
    wd.tasks.each do |t|
      ms = 0
      mw = 0
      ta[t.project.id] ||= { brand: t.project.name, minutes_web: 0, minutes_social: 0 }
      
      t.minutes_social ||= 0
      ms += t.minutes_social

      t.minutes_web ||= 0
      mw += t.minutes_web
      
      ta[t.project.id][:minutes_web] += mw
      ta[t.project.id][:minutes_social] += ms
      ta[t.project.id][:brand] = t.project.name

    end
  end 

  sheet.add_row ["Marchio", "Web", "Social"]

  ta.each do |key, value|
    sheet.add_row [ value[:brand], value[:minutes_web], value[:minutes_social]]
  end  
end

company = Company.all

company.each do |c|
  wb.add_worksheet(name: "#{c.name}") do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row ["Marchio", "Web", "Social", "TOTALE"]
  end
end
```

The export does work and creates the right amount of sheets, but I don't know how to modify my query in order to get my data by company or ordered alphabetically.

Comment: As I can see, you have an association between projects and the company. You can join the company(with includes ofc) in your first query and use `.order_by` to order whatever you want in your query. https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order

Comment: @Grunthor Hi! I modified the query like: `WorkingDay.where(day_date: Date.strptime("2022-09-01", '%Y-%m-%d')..Date.strptime("2022-09-27", '%Y-%m-%d')).includes(:user).includes(tasks: :project).includes(:company).order('companies.name ASC')` but I get this error: )`Can't join 'WorkingDay' to association named 'company'; perhaps you misspelled it?)`

Comment: @Grunthor you're just confusing the poor fella here. The method is called [`.order`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order) not `.order_by`. Also avoid Apidock which just slurps out of date documentation and use the official documentation at api.rubyonrails.org.

Comment: @max The link was correct, It's my fault because of typo. Sorry ;-|

Comment: @RitaPiscopo Try this(not tested)
`WorkingDay.includes(:user).includes({ tasks: { project: :company })
.where(day_date: Date.strptime("2022-09-01", '%Y-%m-%d')..Date.strptime("2022-09-27", '%Y-%m-%d'))
.order('companies.name ASC')` or simpler version
`WorkingDay.includes([{ tasks: { project: :company }, :user])
.where(day_date: Date.strptime("2022-09-01", '%Y-%m-%d')..Date.strptime("2022-09-27", '%Y-%m-%d'))
.order('companies.name ASC')`
Basically in your query, you join Company directly with Working day but you cannot do this because the company is associated with the project.